# Не работают ЧПУ opencart

Tags: opencart, чпу

Opencart 3, использую тему shoppee пытаюсь настроить Чпу, скачал seo pro,  htaccess переименовал, в настройках включил. Как я понимаю после этого урлы должны были  автоматом стать чпу. Но они работают только если вручную их прописывать во вкладке дизайн-seo url, В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0):

Всё верно, после включения ЧПУ вы должны товарам прописать url вручную.

Не знаю какую вы используете версию seo url, но при добавлении нового товара Url будет прописываться автоматически. Если вы хотите автоматически прописать url, где он ещё не указан, то вам нужно найти для этого отдельный модуль.